# How to install mysql native driver

Tags: php, database, web, mysqli

I'm trying to get mysqli_result::fetch_all() to work but I'm out of my depth and butting my head against a wall. This is all being done on remote server and I'm using PuTTY to connect. The internet is telling me to install MySQL Native Driver using the following lines of code:

```
  php ./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
  --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

What I'm getting back is "Could not open input file: ./configure". What do I do now?

Comment: When you say 'trying to get mysqli_result::fetch_all() to work', what specific problem are you getting - errors?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The `mysql_` functions have been deprecated and completely removed in PHP version 7+. Also, don't run `php ./configure`. `configure` isn't a PHP program, it's a script that comes from PHP's source distribution. You'd use it to build PHP from source code.